# How can we report on a Accounts with a Custom Object and exclude by criteria?

Tags: custom-reports, reports-api

I posted [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000BqRZx) in the Trailblazers Community but I haven't been able to resolve the question yet, so thought I'd try my luck here!

We have a custom object related to an Account to track specific features, by Usage Status.

For example:

```
* ABC Company may have:
    - Account Feature "Permission Sets" with Usage Status "Using"
    - Account Feature "Role Hierarchy" with Usage Status "Not Selected"
    - Account Feature "Custom Profiles" with Usage Status "Not Interested"
* XYZ Company may have:
    - Account Feature "Permission Sets" with Usage Status "Not Selected"
    - Account Feature "Role Hierarchy" with Usage Status "Not Selected"
    - Account Feature "Custom Profiles" with Usage Status "Not Selected"
```

We want to create a report to count Accounts that have Account Features ONLY in "Not Selected" status.  So, with the above scenarios,

- we would NOT want ABC Company to appear on that report, even though they have one Account Feature in "Not Selected" status, but
- we WOULD want XYZ Company to appear as ALL their Account Features are in "Not Selected" status

I've tried building:

- a report with either a filter or a cross-filter of "Usage Status = Not Selected", but I am still pulling records that have some Account Feature line items with a different Usage Status,
- a new report type with Accounts w/ w/o Account Features, but that had
  the same results as the Accounts with Account Features report

When I report on "Accounts WITHOUT Account Features where Usage = Not Selected", I get all the other records, but the Accounts I want to see.  And, if I reverse the cross-filter, and say "Accounts WITH Account Features where Usage = Not Selected", I get some results where they have Account Features with Usage of "Not Selected", but also "Using", "Interested", etc.  See [example](https://screenrec.com/share/bxLKBOJja7).

Is there a way to reverse the logic so you ONLY see the records that meet the criteria, rather than excluding them?

I feel like we're missing something really basic, but I haven't been able to get it to work.  Can you help?

Cheers, Nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for two cross filters on your report.

- Accounts with Account Features

  - Usage Status equals Not Selected
- Accounts without Account Features

  - Usage Status not equal to Not Selected

This should give you just the accounts you're looking for.

You may not have realized that you can add [multiple cross-filters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.reports_cross_filters_both.htm&type=5) on a single report.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox - that seems to have worked!  Thank you :)